# How to cast shadows?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I just installed Blender 2.82 and using EEVEE. Camera view is set to *Rendered*, but there is no shadow from an object to a plane underneath it.

Comment: I found an answer to my question at https://blender.community/c/today/1zcbbc/ Thank you.